# Converting an American option to European option

Tags: programming, american-options, european-options

I wonder if there are any websites/resources/sample codes/papers on how to convert the American options to European options (when all else are equal). i.e. if given same underlying asset, same expiration date, same exercise price (but these are unknown). Now additionally we are given the price of an American option, are there resources/equations/formula/sample codes directly converting that American option price to European option price?

Hope you can help. Many thanks!

Best

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, what exactly is unknown? A reasonable estimate in most cases: European = American.

Comment: What do you mean with ''convert''? I don't think there exists a general function $f$ that maps American option prices to equivalent European option prices. You can pick a certain model, find it's parameters by calibration and then back out European-option prices. But first you would need to choose an appropriate model (which easily prices American options). Funny though: normally you take European options for calibration purposes and then price the more complicated model. You propose to do it the other way around

Comment: @BobJansen The price of the European option is unknown, and its price is the ultimate goal. I agree that if  we accept rough estimates, then  Eur=Am. but what I am seeking for is an accurate calculation...

Comment: Accurate calculation without the relevant input is meaningless.

Comment: @Alex Yes here Id love to get the price of European options from a known price of American options. You are probably right that there is no general function, that's why I mention sample codes in my posts-- it could be a complicated process requiring some model specifications and calibration. I wonder whether you have any examples for the procedure you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: "(but these are unknown)", do you mean these are parameters to the model and unknown in advance (when building the model)?

Comment: And what model do you want to assume?

Comment: European option price is the lower bound of the price of the corresponding American option.

Comment: The existence of an expected dividend near the expiration of a call definitely introduces a difference between exercise styles and isn't mentioned in either the question or the existing answer.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your comments and suggestions! I dont understand why this question is closed. Here is what I find in a reference academic paper: in Review of financial studies 2009 by Trolle and Schwartz "Unspanned Stochastic Volatility and the Pricing of Commodity Derivatives" Appendix B. Thanks again!

Comment: @BobJansen Hi Bob, please see my above reply to this question. Sorry I cannot @ you all.
Btw, I am new to this site and dont have that much reputation to vote to reopen my question. wonder if you could help me re-open the question, and add the answer so others interested in similar questions could easily get some clues. Thanks.

Comment: It’s quite unclear to me what the business problem is you’re trying to solve. I think if you can make that clear people will be willing to cast reopen votes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard black-scholes formula to price an european option. The only parameter you do not know to use the formula is the volatility.

If you have the price of an american option then you can use the Cox-Ross-Rubinstein (CRR) model to backout the implied volatility. Then just use black scholes.

The CRR model:

In the framework of the CRR model, the time between now and option expiration is
divided into $N$ sub-periods. Over the course of each sub-period, the security price is
assumed to move either “up” or “down”. The size of the security price move is
determined by the implied volatility and the size of the sub-period. Specifically, the
security price at the end of sub-period $i$ is given by one of the following:
$$ S_{i+1}^{up} = S_i exp(\sigma \sqrt(h))$$
$$ S_{i+1}^{down} = S_i exp(-\sigma \sqrt(h))$$

where $h \equiv T/N$ is the size of the sub-period, and $S_i$ is the security price at the beginning of the sub-period.

To use the CRR approach to value an option, start at the current security price $S$ and
build a “tree” of all the possible security prices at the end of each sub-period, under the assumption that the security price can move only either up or dow.

Next the option is priced at expiration by setting the option expiration value equal to the exercise value: $C = max(S−K,0)$ and $P = max(K−S,0)$. The option price at the beginning of each sub-period is determined by the option prices at the end of the sub-period, using the formula above. Working backwards, the calculated price of the option at time $i=0$ is the theoretical model price.

**To compute the implied volatility of an option given its price, the model is run iteratively with new values of $\sigma$ until the model price of the option converges to its market price, defined as the midpoint of the option’s best closing bid and best closing offer prices. At this point, the final value of $\sigma$ is the option’s implied volatility.**

Then just use that option implied volatility on the standard european black scholes model.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your detailed reply！ I dont know why this question has been closed, but what you suggested is inspiring! Please see the reference in Review of financial studies 2009 paper by Trolle and Schwartz "Unspanned Stochastic Volatility and the Pricing of Commodity Derivatives" Appendix B.Thanks a lot

Comment: You can vote to reopen the question on your post, right below the tags.

Comment: Hi thanks. As I am quite new to this site, what I can see is "share edit flag and delete'. Would you mind helping vote reopen the question so others could easily refer? Appreciate your help@phdstudent